# py.test unit testing over a fixed range of parameter values with failure records

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, pytest

I've written the following type of unit tests for a tool:

```python
param_one = np.random.randint(100, 1000)
param_two = np.random.randint(20, 200)

data1 = generate_random_data(param_one, param_two)
data2 = generate_random_data(param_one, param_two)

def test_one(data1, data2):
    assert something
def test_two(data1, data2):
    assert something
```

I know the tests can fail for a certain combination of these parameters. so I would like to repeat the `py.test` for a specified ranges of the two parameters, and record which combinations of these parameters are failing.

Even better would be

1. if I could save the random data under test when a certain test fails and
2. repeat each test (for each combination of these parameters 10 times) and record the frequency of success/failure.

How can I achieve this under py.test or unittest? Thanks a lot.

I looked up documentation on py.test website and some previous answers here, but the terms are all confusing and it is not easy to follow them.

Obviously, I could do this outside the testing framework, I need this in the unit testing mechanism so I can setup continuous integration better.

Comment: For the start you can you parametrize your tests to run tests with multiple set of data, refer [Paratermtrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) , for repeating your tests `n` times you can either write your own py.test plugin or use this [pytest-repeat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-repeat). In case you need to store the data for which your tests fails, you can write the data to a db or to a file inside your tests on assertion fail.

Comment: [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/) can generate parameters inside constraints, and note the ones which lead to failed tests. It can be used with pytest, but you may find the reporting underwhelming. [This is a known issue, and seems to be blocked on a pytest 3.0 release](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/916).

Comment: Thanks Sanju and theY4Kman.

theY4Kman, thanks for reminding of hypothesis. I knew of it, but I didn't realize how it implemented and failure reports. That may work, let me give it a try.